# Using swap vs assignment for out string parameter of a function

Tags: c++, c++11

If we have a function which is supposed to populate the string value to its out parameter based on some calculation, then which one should we prefer to use and why?

```
void function(string& x)
{
    // In actual code, this value is calculated based on certain conditions
    string temp = "Stack Overflow";

    x.swap(temp);
}
```

Vs

```
void function(string& x)
{
    // In actual code, this value is calculated based on certain conditions
    string temp = "Stack Overflow";

    x = temp;
}
```

Comment: Because `temp` is local inside `function`, and it is not used after assignment, best way is to move its content to `x`: `x = std::move(temp)`.

Comment: You're simply returning a value. There's no use for swapping here.

Comment: There is no reason for using an out-parameter in your example. It's a straight-out pessimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not intend to use `x`'s original contents in `function` anymore after the swap/assignment, then swapping is not necessary.

Assignment will erase the current contents of `x`, but if that is ok, then the (copy) assignment

```
x = temp;
```

is fine.

If you also don't need to use the previous content's of `temp` in `temp` later in `function`, then you can move assign instead:

```
x = std::move(temp);
```

(requires `#include<utility>`)

---

Moving may be faster than copying or swapping, but the details depend on the `std::string` implementation. I would not expect any significant difference in performance between move assignment and swapping, but copy assignment may do an allocation and full copy of the string originally in `temp` and is therefore likely the worst choice in terms of performance.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you probably don't need an out-parameter at all. There is rarely a reason for this. Usually a function's output can be provided as a return value:

```
std::string function()
{
    // In actual code, this value is calculated based on certain conditions
    string temp = "Stack Overflow";

    return temp;
}

//...

std::string result = function();
```

This is always going to be performing better than an out-parameter, because it will always move `temp` into `result` and is even likely to completely optimize away the move operation with the so-called *named return value optimization*, which is not possible with an out-parameter, and because (if the function isn't inlined) it will also not require an additional indirection through the reference in the function parameter.

Even if you have multiple return values, you can still return a `std::pair` or `std::tuple` of them and unpack them on caller site.